# String not displaying in assembly

Tags: x86, nasm, assembly

I'm trying to mess around with some assembly, creating an OS. When this code is loaded into the bootloader, it is suppose to output "This is my cool new OS! Woohoo!ChigginsOS" but right now it says that, minus the "Chiggins" at the end. Where am I going wrong?

```
    BITS 16

start:
    mov ax, 07C0h
    add ax, 288
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 4096

    mov ax, 07C0h
    mov ds, ax

    mov si, text_string
    call print_string

    mov si, name_string
    call print_string

    jmp $ 

    text_string db 'This is my cool new OS! Woohoo!',0
    name_string db 'ChigginsOS',0

;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

exit:
    ret

;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

print_string:
    mov ah, 0Eh

.repeat:
    lodsb
    cmp al, 0
    je .done
    int 10h
    jmp .repeat

.done:
    call exit

;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    times 510-($-$$) db 0
    dw 0xAA55
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not exiting the print_string subroutine: when you execute 'call exit', your are starting a new subroutine, so the 'ret' will return to after the 'call exit' location and start executing the filler after print_string.

Replace 'call exit' with a plain 'ret' and it should work.